# In webview Input box is not working As expected

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-web

I am serving my React Native web website in Webview.

[image]

Input box does not appear once user click it (Keyboard is open)

[image]

When user started typing only half of input box appears

[image]

```
"react-native-webview": "11.17.2",
```

what's wrong?

In normal browser it's working fine.